# Textbox receives only one character from barcode scanner

Tags: excel, vba

when a barcode is scanned only the first number is entered into the textbox.  The code is activated on any changes to textbox.  2nd problem is having focus put on textbox after search has been completed so that next scan can occur.

```
Private Sub Barcode_TxtBox_Change()

If Barcode_TxtBox.Value = "" Then
' set focus back to textbox
    Barcode_TxtBox.Activate
Else
' If match found then populate the box next to the code found with X
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2), Barcode_TxtBox.Value) = 1 Then
        Set TargetCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2).Find(Barcode_TxtBox.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole).Offset(0, 1)
        TargetCell.Value = "X"
    Else
        MsgBox "Code not found"
    End If
' Clear textbox and set focus back to textbox for next scan    
    Barcode_TxtBox.Value = ""

    Barcode_TxtBox.Activate

End If

End Sub
```

When scan is done the first character of barcode is entered into the textbox and no matches are found therefore activating the MSGBox "Code not found"

Comment: Barcode scanners tend to send a "newline" character as the end of the scanned value, so you need to wait for that to appear before you perform the lookup of the value.  Comment out the code in the `Else` block and replace it with `Debug.Print Barcode_TxtBox.Value` and look at the output in the Immediate pane  - that should help

Comment: A scanner is essentially a keyboard with an optical reader instead of keys - it wouldn't surprise me that it sends each character one at a time, and the `Change` handler will run for every single one of them. You want to have a code path that understands the input is partial/incomplete.

Comment: As for the focus issue, try `.SetFocus`